# Maven generate-sources Generates Classes with javax Instead of jakarta Namespace

Tags: java, maven

I'm working on migrating a Java project to use Jakarta EE with Java 17, and I'm facing an issue where running `mvn generate-sources` generates classes using the `javax` namespace instead of the expected jakarta namespace. My project uses JAXB for XML binding, and I've updated my dependencies to use the latest Jakarta EE versions. However, the generated sources still reference javax.xml.bind annotations.

Here's a snippet of my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Other dependencies -->
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.15.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Configuration details -->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Other plugins -->
    </plugins>
</build>
```

've made sure to clean the project (`mvn clean`) before generating sources. Despite this, the output still uses `javax` instead of `jakarta`.

Has anyone faced a similar issue, or does anyone know what might be causing this discrepancy? Any insights or suggestions on how to ensure the generated classes use the `jakarta` namespace would be greatly appreciated.

when inspecting the generated sources in the target/generated-sources directory, I noticed that the annotations are still importing from the javax.xml.bind.annotation package, as shown below:

```
package localhost._8080.beers;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
```

However, I expected these to be imported from the jakarta.xml.bind.annotation package, like so:

```
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
```

Comment: Sounds like that plug-in hasn't been updated.  Maybe you should check Maven Central to see if there's a newer version available.  We're up to JDK 21 as the LTS version.  You should be upgrading from JDK 17, too.

Comment: Using JDK 21 and using the newest versions not have effect

Comment: Just switching to JDK 21 will not do it.  You have to find a new plug-in version.  The suggestion to upgrade to JDK 21 is in addition to that recommendation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you should use 4.x version of jaxb-maven-plugin instead of maven-jaxb2-plugin. See [github](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb-tools?tab=readme-ov-file#jaxb-maven-plugin)